Most efficient way to power a 1.2 V circuit for longevity
I have a circuit that powers an electromagnet pendulum. The circuit works best at 1.2 volts to self start and drive the magnet Bob. The circuit is hit-and-miss on alkaline batteries and doesn't work with lithium batteries, so I have been using rechargeable NiMH batteries (AA).
I currently have a panel mount battery box wired in parallel with two AA NiMH batteries, and the pendulum will swing for two months — about 6 weeks on one NiMH. My question is...how can I make this run longer? Do I add another pack of 2 AAs for a total of 4 NiMH batteries in parallel? Do I run lithium AA at 1.8 V and use a 1.2 volt buck converter? If so, would I wire everything in series? I want to stick with AA batteries and can go up to 4 batteries in my pendulum base.

I'd want to start by examining the mechanical design and working out some details about how aging may impact friction and other factors. Then I'd want to be able to calculate the expected amount of energy lost that must be added back to the system to keep it running. Gap distance, its variability as the pendulum rotates over time, etc. All this in a logbook with experiments performed and data collected and documented. Once I had that then I'd consider designing the circuit and figuring out the source of energy needed for the time needed. I'd then validate the result to check my work too.

You might want to analyze the current draw during the cycle. The fact it's marginal with higher voltage alkaline cells implies that there are brief really high current pulses. Once you have an idea of the peak and mean current you can evaluate the effect of quiescent current and peak current capability of alternate sources, including buck converters. There are lithium AA cells that output ~1.5V, but they are more costly.

Adding to what Sphero said, does adding a large capacitor across the battery make a difference in which cells work?

More 1.2 VDC cells in parallel will make the clock tick longer. A simple way of voltage conversion for oldschool electromagnet clocks is to place a resistor in series. This does work on a Studebaker   car clock. So if you measure the DCR of the electromagnet and add to this to raise the operating voltage accordingly. In my case the client wanted to keep 6 V original clock in car that was converted to 12 V. This calls for a fixed resistor of the same value of the clock DCR. This keeps coil current the same keeping operation the same. I fitted the nearest NOS       preferred value thru hole part from my junkbox and clock is fine. If you want to go from 1.2 to 1.8 then add half the measured DCR. This is much smaller and simpler than buck and it does not waste much power because unlike the buck there is no idle current.

I've since done more testing. The optimal working voltage of the circuit is actually 1.4 volts which is why I have had success with NiMH batteries but not with alkaline or lithium AAs. Ultimately, I would like the circuit to be able to work on all three of these batteries. Is this possible? I recently tried a buck/boost but with four batteries in series and dropped the voltage to 1.4 V but I only got 2 days of swing time. So I think I need to keep the batteries in parallel like you said. The resistance of the coil is about 30 ohms. You're suggesting a resistor?
